# Starting Activity from Background on WearOS 4

Tags: android, android-permissions, wear-os, wearables

I'm currently working on a small project developing a standalone alarm app for WearOS, primarily targeting WearOS 4.
The app needs to start an Activity when an alarm is received. However, I'm facing an issue where this Activity gets aborted because it's being started from the background without the necessary permissions.

After looking here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts
I've tried adding the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission.
The part where I got stuck is, as far as I can tell, WearOS 4 doesn't seem to have a setting for overlay permissions AT ALL.
This makes the "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permission pretty much useless in my case.

Does anyone have experience dealing with this issue, or can offer some advice on how to handle this situation?

Comment: Have you tried switching to [displaying a high-priority `Notification`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#display-notification) instead?

Comment: The Activity that supposed to be strated has a Desposiable Affect that starts vibrating to wake the user up. Obviously displaying a notification won't wake the user up... Is there a way around this?

Comment: "Obviously displaying a notification won't wake the user up" -- why won't it? Have you tried it?

Comment: Ok I gess I am missing something then (absolute beginner in Android development). Isnt a notification is just something displayed in the UI?

Comment: No. Notifications are a system level feature designed to alert the user to something. If you start using Android devices, you will see notifications for things like incoming messages, available updates,... and alarm clocks. See [the documentation for notifications in general](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications) and [the documentation for watch notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications).